# Spring Feign: Failover

Tags: failover, spring-cloud, hystrix

I have just tested Spring Feign and found out, that there is no immidate failover mechanism.

I have a service A, that calls service B. Service B had 2 instances and I checked, that balancing works - both were called. But when I stopped one of them, for some time I was getting error pages when calling service A - because could not connect with B.

I was kind of expecting, that there is also a failover in feign, so A would automatically try with other B instance, when found problems. Or do I have to implement it directly, with Hystrix for example?

Answer (score 0):

Spring Cloud Netflix Feign uses [Ribbon](https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon) as the load-balancer. The situation you described is particular to [Ribbon](https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon/wiki/Programmers-Guide) coupled with [Eureka](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Configuring-Eureka), not Feign. You are correct that the bad instance will be cached for the default of 30 seconds. You can configure ribbon to retry certain methods (which would then request the remaining good server). You can also shorten the length of the life of the eureka/ribbon cache with `eureka.client.registryFetchIntervalSeconds=5` (for 5 seconds rather than 30).

Hystrix helps with a fallback for dealing with failure responses and as a circuit breaker if there is a systematic failure).

Comment: Thanks for answer. I didn't mentioned it here, but I do use eureka as DS. That is another issue I don't quite follow: Eureka does not recognize itself, that a service is dead (cause service is not pinging Eureka anymore) until it is explicitely DELETEed from Eureka...

So as I see it currently, a stack of Eureka/Ribbon/Feign an do so will NOT be really resilient to a case, a service goes down uncleanly - system will still try to use it, will not discard it. And we have to implement some additional monitoring to remove dead services from Eureka (or are there such already?)

Comment: Eureka has a self preservation mode that kicks in if certain conditions are met. That is what you are seeing. I see it when there are small numbers of instances and only one eureka.